# How to save data when user select radionbutton from radiobuttongroup in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, model, radio-button

I am making one quiz app. I have 10 questions list and each have four option. User select answer one by one. Than all answers save and give result in last screen.

//Here is my json reference.

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Success",
    "quiz_id": "",
    "attemp": "",
    "last_question_id": "",
    "question_list": [
        {
            "questionId": "19_0",
            "questionName": "research",
            "answerId": "19_0_2",
            "user_answer": "",
            "option_list": [
                "put forward (an idea or plan) for consideration or discussion by others",
                "bring (something) to an end",
                "investigate systematically",
                "bring (something) to an end"
            ],
            "hard_question": "0",
            "synonyms": "",
            "additional": "",
            "moreInfo": "",
            "grammarfunction": "",
            "correct": false
        },
```

Comment: do you have any written code ?. for this type of logic there is many way to do it .

Comment: Nope I am new in programming so can not understand logic.

Comment: Any updates Mr. Ankit?

Answer (score 0):

please reference this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-how-to-build-a-quiz-game-596d0f369575

you can fork this example directly. https://github.com/frideosapps/trivia_example

[image]